# Execute Task Everyday at Midnight - Grails 3.2.2

Tags: grails, groovy, scheduled-tasks

I have a method like `MyController.foo()` and I want to execute it every day at 00:00.

I have seen some solutions that use a TimerTask with a 1 day delay in seconds, but the day of time change it will bring some errors.

So ... What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to enable scheduling using spring boot annotation:

```
@EnableScheduling
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

Then you can put @Scheduled annotation on your methods:

```
@Scheduled(cron="00 00 * * *")
def foo() {
    //do something
}
```

Cron expression `00 00 * * *` means execute every midnigth.

Comment: Do I have to add anything to the controller holding `foo()` method?

Comment: Should I place that method in a Controller or in a Service?

Comment: Service is better place for scheduled tasks.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but just in case you need more complexity later, you can also look at the quartz plugin: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/ which provides this, and other capabilities.  If all you need is basic cron, just do what is suggested here!

Comment: I have compiled quartz plugin, because I need to specify a TimeZone, but it doesn't work, in the plugin docs it says I need to add quartz 2.1.x*: grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/latest/guide/introduction.html , but how do I add this quartz to my project? @Daniel